# c# sorting list by substring

Tags: c#

i have a list of strings:

```
\\\\Tecan1\\tecan #1 output\\15939-E.ESY\r\n
\\\\Tecan1\\tecan #1 output\\15942-E.ESY\r\n
\\\\Tecan1\\tecan #1 output\\15945-E.ESY\r\n
\\\\Tecan1\\tecan #1 output\\15948-E.ESY\r\n
\\\\Tecan1\\tecan #1 output\\15951-E.ESY\r\n
\\\\Tecan1\\tecan #1 output\\15954-E.ESY\r\n
\\\\Tecan1\\tecan #1 output\\15957-E.ESY\r\n
\\\\Tecan1\\tecan #1 output\\15960-E.ESY\r\n
\\\\Tecan1\\tecan #1 output\\15963-E.ESY\r\n
\\\\Tecan_2\\output on tecan 2\\15940-E.ESY\r\n
\\\\Tecan_2\\output on tecan 2\\15943-E.ESY\r\n
\\\\Tecan_2\\output on tecan 2\\15946-E.ESY\r\n
\\\\Tecan_2\\output on tecan 2\\15949-E.ESY\r\n
\\\\Tecan_2\\output on tecan 2\\15952-E.ESY\r\n
\\\\Tecan_2\\output on tecan 2\\15955-E.ESY\r\n
\\\\Tecan_2\\output on tecan 2\\15958-E.ESY\r\n
\\\\Tecan_2\\output on tecan 2\\15961-E.ESY\r\n
\\\\Tecan-5\\Output\\15941-E.ESY\r\n
\\\\Tecan-5\\Output\\15944-E.ESY\r\n
\\\\Tecan-5\\Output\\15947-E.ESY\r\n
\\\\Tecan-5\\Output\\15950-E.ESY\r\n
\\\\Tecan-5\\Output\\15953-E.ESY\r\n
\\\\Tecan-5\\Output\\15956-E.ESY\r\n
\\\\Tecan-5\\Output\\15959-E.ESY\r\n
\\\\Tecan-5\\Output\\15962-E.ESY\r\n
```

each \r\n should be a new line. sorry for the bad formatting

i need to sort the list of by the file name `15939-E.ESY`, etc... i need the entire list in alphanumerical order by the filename. how would i sort it this way?

Comment: Do you have any code? That might show what kind of list it is for instance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd use `Path.GetFileName` like this

```
list = list.OrderBy(s=>Path.GetFileName(s)).ToList();
```

Where `list` is a collection of those lines.

Comment: just tried this and did not do anything . should i be sitting list = list.orderby........?

Comment: @herrow yeah you have to capture the IEnumberable that is returned.  If you want to set it to the list you'll need a `ToList` on the end.  See my updated answer.

Comment: @herrow Yes. The method [returns an IOrderedEnumerable<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx), it does not sort the list in-place.